# Drawing a path in Photoshop/Illustrator, using it in iOS

Tags: path, photoshop, cakeyframeanimation, cgpath, cashapelayer

I am looking for a more convenient way of drawing a path than by drawing it programmatically. Is there any way of drawing a path in Photoshop (or Illustrator) and getting that path to the iPhone to use in a CAKeyframeAnimation? e.g. by exporting the point data, or by importing the .ai file?

Comment: I'm no iphone developer, but I imagine you could parse an SVG saved from illustrator, and use the bezier points for your animation.

Comment: Actually that was a great pointer. Found this: http://likethought.com/opacity/ It will export Quartz code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity). Opacity is a nifty little program that will allow you to draw paths (or import images) and export source code for iOS (e.g. Quartz).

Answer (score 4):

There's a [GitHub project called "PocketSVG"](https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG) that can create UIBezier objects from SVG files. It works perfectly with shapes created in Adobe Illustrator and exported to SVG Tiny 1.2.